# Sonar periodic email reports

Tags: email, jenkins, report, sonarqube

Is it possible to have Sonar sending periodic (To be more specific, weekly) reports by email? I need to have it analyzing as there are new builds, but report only weekly.
Currently i'm running sonar as a jenkins plugin set to analyze whether there is a new build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the report that you want to use but this is the way we have been using to test the report before looking at the commercial edition that has an email feature. We have been using the Sonar PDF Plugin at:
**http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/PDF+Plugin**

This generates a report of the metrics, violations, other details, and then puts these into a pdf which is generated after a sonar analysis. This pdf is located at a static link such as: **SonarServer:9000/api/plugins/Pdfreport/getReport?resource=3955** 
You can then use Jenkins to send a weekly, biweekly, monthly, etc email with this link attached. It is a workaround to getting out metrics less often.

Comment: The link doesn't seem to exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about some digest feature, this is not possible yet.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the Sonar Web Service along with its Client:-

http://myvogonpoetry.com/wp/2013/02/21/using-the-sonar-rest-api-for-weekly-emails/

We use this too but a little differently. This should be perfect for you with an automated job that separately handles it.